# In Espresso, how to use `render` as action name?

Tags: ruby

Started moving my site from Rails to [Espresso](http://e.github.com/)

My old site has lot of pages like `/render/TYPE/ID` indexed in Google.

But in Espresso `render` is used to render templates and can not use it as action?

```
class CMS < E
  map :/

  # other actions

  def render
    # this is overriding Espresso's `render` method
    # and i'm unable to render my templates?
  end
end
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended way to define actions in Espresso are: `http verb + action name`

So your render action would look like `get_render` for GET requests, `post_render` for POST requests, etc.

"Verbless" actions are allowed just for convenience.

Your controller:

```
class CMS < E
  map :/

  # other actions

  def get_render
    # use `render` to render your templates
  end
end
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you